# iOS application getting crashed "Could not set up parent class, due to: Invalid generic instantiation"

Tags: ios, .net, maui, maui-blazor

In dotnet maui webview project is keeping crashing when i deploy into ios device, it works perfect on android and windows machine, below is the error i get

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'Could not set up parent class, due to: Invalid generic instantiation assembly:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BBD837B4-54F3-4EEA-90B3-AB342A31E893/Documents/<AppName>.App.content/Microsoft.Maui.dll type:ViewHandler`2 member:(null)'. Callstack: '   at System.RuntimeType.GetConstructors_internal(BindingFlags bindingAttr, RuntimeType reflectedType)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetConstructorCandidates(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, Boolean allowPrefixLookup)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetDefaultConstructor()
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono(Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.Internal.MauiFactory.CreateInstance(ServiceDescriptor item)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.Internal.MauiFactory.GetService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.Internal.MauiFactory.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceDescriptor single, IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.Internal.MauiFactory.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.Internal.MauiHandlersFactory.GetHandler(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToUIViewController(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.MapContent(IWindowHandler handler, IWindow window)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IWindow, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IWindowHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.SetHandler(INativeObject nativeElement, IElement element, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.SetWindowHandler(UIWindow platformWindow, IWindow window, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IApplication application, UIWindowScene windowScene, NSDictionary[] states)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IUIApplicationDelegate platformApplication, IApplication application, UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String[] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName)
   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass)
   at <AppName>.App.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\silvi\source\repos\Dietai\Dietai.App\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:line 13
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)'
```

I had create a new blank dotnet maui app on the same environment and it worked fine, i dont even know where to start

Comment: Is this on iOS 16? If you have access to a device or emulator with an earlier version of iOS, test on that for now.

Comment: You said: "I had create a new blank dotnet maui app on the same environment and it worked fine", did you reference some Nuget packages in your crashed project, and your crash log pointed to `System.RuntimeType.GetConstructors_internal`, Can you tell me how you use it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.